# How are the axons in the white matter bundled?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

I wonder if the following question concerning the axons in the white matter does make sense.

It is common knowledge that white matter is "[composed mainly of bundles of myelinated axons](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-ap/chapter/collections-of-nervous-tissue/)" resp. is "[mainly made up of myelinated axons, also called tracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_matter)" (= "[bundle of nerve fibers (axons)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_tract)".

For the following to make sense the following assumptions are made:

- All axons making up a bundle are of approximately same length $L$. (Of course not *all* axons have the same length!)
- Axons run in parallel as long as possible.
- Axons normally don't branch inside the white matter. (Or is this a totally unrealistic assumption?)

Assume that it is a sensible definition of a bundle to be the set of axons running densely packed inside a *virtual* tube of length $l = \alpha L$, $\alpha < 1$. By this definition sub-bundles of a bundle would also be bundles, so we are interested only in *maximal* bundles.

It's important to notice that the definition of bundles depends on the parameter $\alpha$: smaller $\alpha$ means the axons must run in parallel only for a shorter distance (compared to their common length $L$), larger $\alpha$ means the axons must run in parallel for a longer distance. Smaller $\alpha$ means less but larger bundles, larger $\alpha$ means more, but smaller bundles.

Note that each bundle (independent of $\alpha$) defines two specific cortical regions (the two regions of the source and target neurons of the axons). For the smallest bundles (largest $\alpha$) their diameters correspond well to the size of the source and target regions (see picture below).

See here different partitions into bundles with $\alpha \approx 0.5$ (grey, 1 bundle), $\alpha \approx 0.75$ (blue, 2 bundles) and $\alpha \approx 1$ (red, 4 bundles):

[image]

For the sake of simplicity, assume that - for a given $\alpha$ - bundles don't overlap, i.e. each axon is contained in only one bundle. (This might be an oversimplification.)

My question is:

> **Can a rough estimate be given, how many bundles with a given number $N$ of neurons are there in the white matter (for a given $\alpha$)?** (Choose the organism you like or know of.)

I suppose the largest bundle to be found in the brain is the corpus callosum which - as a tube - has a rather short length (small $\alpha$). It contains (in the *macaca nemestrina* brain) about [$10^8$](https://depts.washington.edu/fasdpn/pdfs/miller-1999.pdf) axons.

For the sake of simplicity, let's consider only powers of ten. Then for a small $\alpha$ which would allow the corpus callosum to be a bundle, we will get as a "null hypothesis" (with purely hypothetical numbers of bundles!):

[image]

But maybe the distribution is somehow bimodal, e.g. like this:

[image]

Is a reliable answer to this question out of reach today? Don't we know enough about the long-range structure of the white matter? Or did just nobody take the effort to make this statistics? Or can I find it somewhere?